# Redirect Hierarchical (Nested) URLs to Flat URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, hierarchical

First question here :).

A site we run currently uses hierarchical (nested) URLs e.g. example.com/folder/page/

We would now prefer flat URLs e.g. example.com/page/

Our CMS can easily allow a switch to pages being given flat URLs. However it does not handle the redirects from the old hierarchical URLs. It looks like it needs to be handled in the .htaccess file.

There are 250+ pages so it would be preferable to have code that would handle all the redirects rather than doing a redirect 301 for each URL.

Can anyone provide some .htaccess code or point me in the right direction to achieve the redirects?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the most efficient thing in the world, but I do this on my blog using a big `.htaccess` file containing:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/old/url http://example.com/new-url
```

If you can edit the main Apache config file instead of using `.htaccess` files, it will likely be more efficient to use [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) instead of `RedirectMatch` (which is easier to use inside `.htaccess` files because, if I recall, it matches against the URL relative to the `.htaccess` file instead of… something else… when `Redirect` is involved. But I could be wrong about that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your .htaccess under $DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=5

RewriteRule ^folder(/page/.*)$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]
```